futurebuilder run before initialized
I have a folder that contains a number of photos in Firebase Storage.
I would like to get the image, assigned to photoUrl are late Future class, inside of initState.
But what happens is that futurebuilder think they already have the data before initialization is completed and run a code under state.hasData.
Please teach me what seems to be the issue.
Following are code I'm currently writting
late Future photoUlr;

imageGetter() async {
  final List<String> photoUrls = [];
  final productTop = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("product").listAll();
  productTop.items.forEach((Reference ref) async {
    await ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
      String val = value.toString();
      print(val);
      photoUrls.add(val);
    });
  });
  return photoUrls;
}

@override
 void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
  photoUlr = imageGetter();
}

///////////later in scaffold////////
FutureBuilder(
   future: photoUlr,
   builder: (context, snapshot) {

I believe the code above should be able to initialize the photoUlr in initstate. But like I said above ,futurebuilder runs a snapshot.hasData code before initialization is completed. I've confirmed this since the print code in imageGetter runs after the print code of snapshot.hasData.
Just as a note I tried to solve the issue by get rid of await in the imageGetter function by using the method below.
Is there any way to iterate over future<list> in flutter
but I was not able to solve the issue since they told me Future is not iterable.

Assign the Future method to the FutureBuilder directly.
FutureBuilder(
   future: imageGetter(),
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
       ...
        }
)

That's because that line:
photoUlr = imageGetter();

the variable photoUrl is suspected whether it successfully get initialized or not.
